# Is it possible to set a JavaFX static property in CSS?

Tags: css, javafx, javafx-2, fxml, javafx-css

Sample FXML with the BorderPanel.alignment ["static property"](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#static_property_elements):

```
<BorderPane>
  <top>
    <Label text="My Label" BorderPanel.alignment="CENTER"/>           
  </top>
</BorderPane>
```

The CSS-supported version:

```
<BorderPane stylesheets="Style.css">
   <top>
     <Label text="My Label" styleClass="labelClass"/>           
   </top>
</BorderPane>
```

Style.css would be:

```
.labelClass
 {
   -fx-borderpanel-alignement: center
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For JavaFX versions 2.0 to 2.2 => no you cannot set the static layout properties via css.

You can create a feature request in the [JavaFX jira](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com) to ask this functionality be implemented in a future JavaFX version.

Comment: Thanks, just created the feature request.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply it programatically. For example if you want to center all the widgets of a `GridPane`, instead of writing `GridPane.halignment="CENTER"` in the XML declaration of each widget, you can do this in Java :

```
for(Node node : gridPane.getChildren())
{
    GridPane.setHalignment(node, HPos.CENTER);
}
```

Unfortunately I don't think you can factorize layouts as in Android :(