# How can use a layout fro my JavaFX widgets?

Tags: java, css, javafx, fxml

In android there is the `style=""` attribute that refers to a style/layout applied to that widget. This way, I can factorize the code of similar widgets and apply that style to all these widgets.

Now there is also a `style=""` attribute in JavaFX but it refers to a CSS content, and the code I want to factorize is not CSS.

More concretely, I have many buttons for example like this (FXML file) :

```
    <Text text="Source"
      GridPane.rowIndex="0"
      GridPane.columnIndex="0"
      GridPane.columnSpan="2"
      GridPane.halignment="CENTER"/>
```

And what they all have in common in this case is the `GridPane.halignment="CENTER"`. I'll agree with you that in this specific case, it would only be replacing one line by another. But if I also have other redondant attributes ...

So is there anything such as layouts that can be applied to widgets in JavaFX please ? Alternatively, can you do everything in CSS, in which case how would you translate this `GridPane.halignment="CENTER"` in JavaFX CSS ?

```
.text
{
    // code
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I hardly get your question. Please elaborate, or your question will soon be closed as "unclear what's being asked".

Comment: I think my question was perfectly clear. I want to set a style to all the widgets but not CSS, things like `GridPane.halignment="CENTER"`. What don't you understand exactly ?

Comment: I'm not completely sure but apparently according to this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11691931/is-it-possible-to-set-a-javafx-static-property-in-css it's not possible in JavaFX.

Comment: I posted a workaround in the other duplicate topic.